# Docker runs without a problem but i cant reach the site from the given url

Tags: docker, gunicorn

```
[2021-02-22 11:24:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-02-22 11:24:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2021-02-22 11:24:59 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-02-22 11:24:59 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
```

When i open the url it seems the server is not working. I use Django for the web app. It works fine when i build the docker or start the app using

```
python manage.py runserver
```

But when i do

```
docker run app
```

it does not work.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEzb2.png)

DOCKER FILE:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
EXPOSE 8000
ENV VAR1=10
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app.wsgi"]
```

## The working answer:

=> docker run -p 8000:8000 app then connect to http://localhost:8000 from your browser.

#### from Zeitounator.

Comment: What does your docker file look like?

Comment: "http://localhost:8000/" is this correct because it returns "localhost refused to connect."

Comment: How your docker file so we can see how you have built the image, and the docker command your running to start the container

Comment: How did you map that port to your local machine ? What else to you have in your container logs when your try to connect ?

Comment: => `docker run -p 8000:8000 app` then connect to `http://localhost:8000` from your browser.

Comment: => docker run -p 8000:8000 app then connect to http://localhost:8000 from your browser. Thanks a lot. This works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend you to use docker-compose for running and using your image and set any environment variables you want.
A sample of the docker-compose file could be like this:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  my_simple_site:
    image: my_simple_site:0.0.0
    container_name: my_simple_site
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - GUNICORN_WORKER_NUM=1
```

You can see the number of workers (`GUNICORN_WORKER_NUM`) you can pass over environment variables.
after that for running your app over Gunicorn use a config file. A config file could be like below in python. For example, I created this in a file named `gunicorn.conf.py` for later use:

```
import os

bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = os.getenv('GUNICORN_WORKER_NUM', 1)
timeout = 200
user = 'root'
directory = '/address/to/your/app'
```

Afterward, you can use it in your DockerFile like this:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "/address/to/cofingfile/gunicorn.conf.py", 
"app.wsgi"]
```

For further improvements, It's better to use supervisor and Nginx for your project.

Comment: Your recommendations (compose, nginx) could be good, but they don't answer the question. In some projects you're unable to use other tools when there is a way to do it without.

Comment: Also, good one linking the config file to the command instead of passing everything